# How to get the content of the webview before it is displayed?

Tags: android

How to get the content of the webview before it is displayed?

1. I use the webview to load the first URL which is a form.
2. After the user click the sumbit button of the form(it is from 1), the webview will go to the second URL.
3. I need to get the content of the second URL to do some special action. But I don't know how to get the content.

The two URLs are from the server side. My APP is the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this problem. I use the this method: http://lexandera.com/2009/01/extracting-html-from-a-webview/

Answer (score 1):

override the onPageStarted or in your WebViewClient

```
@Override
         public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
             // do stuff before loading the url
         }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know this function, but it can't meet my requirement. I can only detect the second url but I don't know the submited data in the first url. The result of the second url is with the relevant the first url.I need to post the sumbit data with the second url. But If use the webview, it can display the result. But I don't need to display the data in the webview.

Comment: Is it your own webpage (and your are able/allowed to edit)? You want the data submitted by the form on which the second url is loaded?

Comment: If you can edit your page read this link:
http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/01/01/using-webview-to-call-a-function-in-android-java-code-or-how-to-use-a-webviewclient-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

Using WebViewClient class you can do by this way

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
         // do stuff before loading the url
    }
});
```